# ssh to raspberry pi zero w no longer works after updating software

Tags: ssh

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

My raspberry **pi zero** w with latest version **av Raspbian Jessi** worked fine yesterday and I had no problems to ssh to it from my windows 10 pc. Today I updated it with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y

sudo reboot
```

After it is up again I am no longer able to ssh to it. I get the following error message when I try to ssh to it:

```
PuTTY Fatal Error

Network error: Software caused connection abort
```

I tried setting up enabling it again from **raspi-config** followed by a reboot, but that does not help.

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the SSH daemon running on the Pi?  What is the full error message from putty?

Comment: Thank you for your response, Joan. I did not think it was relevant to mention it in my post, but the only thing that i left out from the putty error message i received was the "x" error icon in the message and the "OK" button, otherwise the error message that i received from it is exactly as i had posted. The daemon.log file indicated that the ssh daemon could not be run because of a key that was in the wrong format. Since this appeared to indicate that data has been corrupted on the disk i decided to make a clean start: clean the disk, reformat it (erase everything), and reimage the raspi.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you may not have enabled the SSH daemon. As a security measure ssh is off by default. You can enable it – for the next boot – by creating an empty file called `ssh` in the root of your boot device. The easiest way to do this is to mount the SD card on another computer and the create the file. The contents of the file are ignored and it is deleted at boot.

To make the change permanent:

1. Run `sudo raspi-config`
2. Select option 5 (Interfacing)
3. Enable ssh
4. Change your password (option 1)